# HandleError attribute in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, themes, orchardcms

I'm using HandleError attribute in an Orchard module.
I would like to display a custom view to user when a specific exception occurs.
I'm using this code:

```
[HttpPost, Themed]
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(LogOnException), View = "LogonError")]
public ActionResult LogOn(FbUser user)
{
  ...
```

Currently it works but the view is rendered without theme.
Is there a way to render in the current theme?
Thanks